# List all directories in home folder with fd

Tags: shell, zsh, fzf, fd

I'm trying to write a shell function to rapidly `cd` into any directory in my home folder, using the `fd` and `fzf` programs.

This is what I have so far

```
function fdcd() {
  cd "$(fd --type d --ignore-file ~/.config/fd/ignore --hidden | fzf)"
}
```

which has two problems:

1) it only lists the directories contained in my current working directory, instead of every directory in my home folder;

2) idk if this is my shell's fault, but after I use this command my shell prompt doesn't immediately update to the new directory, instead I have to issue a command (even a blank one) first for it to update, which is annoying.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fdcd() {
  local dir
  dir=$(
    cd &&
      fd -0 --type d --ignore-file ~/.config/fd/ignore --hidden |
      fzf --read0
  ) && cd ~/$dir
}
```

As to why your prompt is not updated automatically, note that the prompt is only re-computed and re-drawn once you enter the line editor or when a zle widget explicitly asks for it to be redrawn (`reset-prompt` / `clear-screen` widgets) or returns after having invalidated the display (`zle -I`) or when the shell handles some asynchronous events.

So, if that `fdcd` functions is meant to be called as or as part of a custom `zle` widget, you'll need to ask the prompt to be recomputed if you want the change of directory to be reflected in the prompt:

```
fdcd() {
  local dir
  dir=$(
    cd &&
      fd ${NUMERIC:+-d$NUMERIC} -0 --type d \
        --ignore-file ~/.config/fd/ignore --hidden |
      fzf --read0
  ) && cd ~/$dir || return
  if zle; then
    # allow fdcd to run inside and outside zle
    zle reset-prompt
  fi
}
zle -N fdcd
bindkey '\es' fdcd
```

Here also making use of the `$NUMERIC` argument to limit the depth of the search, so you type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for instance to limit the search to depth 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot. To make the prompt update automatically I needed the command `zle reset-prompt`.

Comment: @noibe, OK. I take it that `fdcd` is invoked as part of or as a zle widget?

Comment: Yes, it is. I probably should have included that info.

Comment: @noibe, yes, it's the root of the issue here. See edit for some suggestion of improvement

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I recently started using the `vcs_info` framework to display `git` related infos in the prompt, and if I use `fdcd` as a zle widget the prompt doesn't get updated even though I'm including a `zle reset-prompt`. [This](https://pastebin.com/RJXZpE6p) is my `vcs_info` setup.